# Backing up a SQL Server database from hard disk with stored procedures?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, database-backups

I can backup a database on hard disk with the following method :

```
void BackUp(string ConnectionString, string DatabaseFullPath, string backUpPath)
{
    progressBar1.Value = 0;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        con.Open();

        string UseMaster = "USE master";
        SqlCommand UseMasterCommand = new SqlCommand(UseMaster, con);
        UseMasterCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        progressBar1.Value += 25;

        string Alter1 = @"ALTER DATABASE [" + DatabaseFullPath + "] SET Single_User WITH Rollback Immediate";
        SqlCommand Alter1Cmd = new SqlCommand(Alter1, con);
        Alter1Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        progressBar1.Value += 25;

        string Restore = @"BACKUP DATABASE [" + DatabaseFullPath + "] TO  DISK = N'" + backUpPath + @"' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'" + DatabaseFullPath + "-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10";
        SqlCommand RestoreCmd = new SqlCommand(Restore, con);
        RestoreCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        progressBar1.Value += 25;

        string Alter2 = @"ALTER DATABASE [" + DatabaseFullPath + "] SET Multi_User";
        SqlCommand Alter2Cmd = new SqlCommand(Alter2, con);
        Alter2Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        progressBar1.Value += 25;

        labelReport.Text = "Successful";
    }
}
```

and , How can I convert it to a Stored Procedure ?

(I'm newbie in SQL Server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intent is to encapsulate the backup task in a stored procedure purely so it can be executed from C#, then maybe you want to consider [SQL Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) (SMO) instead? These objects give you programmatic access to SQL Server administration tasks such as performing backups. Check out the second sample here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162133.aspx

---

**Edit:** But to answer the question, you can follow this example which works for me:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BackupDatabase
(
    @databaseName sysname, 
    @backupPath varchar(260)
)
AS
BEGIN
    BACKUP DATABASE @databaseName 
        TO DISK = @backupPath
        WITH FORMAT;
END
GO
```

called by

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[BackupDatabase]
        @databaseName = play,
        @backupPath = N'c:\backup\play.bak'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Comment: Actually, I saw it before, but I couldn't create the above `SP` by myself.

Comment: Thanks, But my Database is on Hard Disk beside of my Win App exe file !

Comment: Edited, however I don't believe your DatabaseFullPath parameter can be the path to the mdf file as it isn't valid syntax. It will be the database name.

Also I don't believe your DB needs to be in single-user mode to perform the backup

Comment: `Also I don't believe your DB needs to be in single-user mode to perform the backup` I'm sure about it, I edited the first post. I wanna to do it with `SP`